# Why does Short not affect entity lists?

Tags: output-formatting, entity

[`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short.html) seems not to have an effect on the display of the following list of entities, while it works fine on a list of strings. Why is this?

[image]

Here's the copyable code:

```
EntityList[EntityClass["PeriodicTiling", All]] // Short

EntityValue[EntityClass["PeriodicTiling", All], "Name"] // Short
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short) takes an optional second argument specifying how many "lines" to show. If you set this argument to a smaller value than the default (which I think is 1), you will get a shorter output:

```
EntityList[EntityClass["PeriodicTiling",All]] //Short[#,.2]&
```

[image]

I agree that the [`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short) behavior for entities is unexpected.

Comment: Perhaps `Short` thinks that entities take up less horizontal space than they really do?